How to pull ratings from Chess.com and Lichess automatically?
We use a chess club and class management system that gets up to date ratings from ECF (English Chess Federation). Is it possible to do the same for Chess.com and Lichess and how?

In addition to the answer while not a duplicate the answer to Downloading Games From Lichess might be helpful, at least for Lichess

You can get user current rating from Lichess using /api/user/{username}, which returns JSON with key "perfs", in which are current ratings by time control category.
For rating history you can use /api/user/{username}/rating-history.

chess.com has a public API: https://www.chess.com/news/view/published-data-api#pubapi-endpoint-player-stats
URL pattern: https://api.chess.com/pub/player/{username}/stats
Example output:
$ curl -s 'https://api.chess.com/pub/player/hikaru/stats' | jq 
{
  "chess_daily": {
    "last": {
      "rating": 2239,
      "date": 1694547202,
      "rd": 103
    },
    "best": {
      "rating": 2464,
      "date": 1397136740,
      "game": "https://www.chess.com/game/daily/84604826"
    },
    "record": {
      "win": 73,
      "loss": 11,
      "draw": 4,
      "time_per_move": 32755,
      "timeout_percent": 0
    }
  },
  "chess960_daily": {
    "last": {
      "rating": 1231,
      "date": 1444458214,
      "rd": 230
    },
    "best": {
      "rating": 1489,
      "date": 1397073007,
      "game": "https://www.chess.com/game/daily/87191830"
    },
    "record": {
      "win": 1,
      "loss": 2,
      "draw": 0,
      "time_per_move": 32755,
      "timeout_percent": 0
    }
  },
  "chess_rapid": {
    "last": {
      "rating": 2762,
      "date": 1715460607,
      "rd": 49
    },
    "best": {
      "rating": 2927,
      "date": 1645902514,
      "game": "https://www.chess.com/game/live/61144117987"
    },
    "record": {
      "win": 170,
      "loss": 48,
      "draw": 172
    }
  },
  "chess_bullet": {
    "last": {
      "rating": 3317,
      "date": 1716659796,
      "rd": 37
    },
    "best": {
      "rating": 3570,
      "date": 1605136047,
      "game": "https://www.chess.com/game/live/5710095242"
    },
    "record": {
      "win": 13030,
      "loss": 1782,
      "draw": 805
    }
  },
  "chess_blitz": {
    "last": {
      "rating": 3175,
      "date": 1717623525,
      "rd": 32
    },
    "best": {
      "rating": 3405,
      "date": 1707519571,
      "game": "https://www.chess.com/game/live/59245152619"
    },
    "record": {
      "win": 27992,
      "loss": 4681,
      "draw": 3671
    }
  },
  "fide": 2814,
  "tactics": {
    "highest": {
      "rating": 3902,
      "date": 1710574172
    },
    "lowest": {
      "rating": 695,
      "date": 1389043648
    }
  },
  "puzzle_rush": {
    "best": {
      "total_attempts": 126,
      "score": 123
    }
  }
}



Thanks for sharing for chess.com too. Can't have 2 accepted answers or this one would be included

A sample python script for Lichess, chess.com and FIDE.
1. Lichess
"""Gets Lichess user ratings given username.

API: https://lichess.org/api
"""

import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

username = input('Input your Lichess username? ')
user_json = urlopen("http://en.lichess.org/api/user/" + username).read()
user_perfs = json.loads(user_json)['perfs']

print(f'username: {username}')
for k in user_perfs:
    rating = user_perfs[k].get('rating')
    if rating:
        print(f'{k}: {rating}')

Sample run
Input your Lichess username? zhigalko_sergei
username: zhigalko_sergei
ultraBullet: 2472
bullet: 3250
blitz: 2828
rapid: 2948
classical: 1500
correspondence: 1500
chess960: 2777
kingOfTheHill: 2630
threeCheck: 2576
racingKings: 1698
crazyhouse: 2547
puzzle: 2822

2. chess.com
"""Gets user ratings from chess.com given username

API: https://www.chess.com/news/view/published-data-api
"""

import urllib.request
import json

username = input('Input your chess.com username? ')
url = f"https://api.chess.com/pub/player/{username}/stats"

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
    data = response.read().decode()
    player_stats = json.loads(data)

    print(f'username: {username}')
    for k in player_stats:
        try:
            rating = player_stats[k]['last'].get('rating')
        except KeyError:
            pass
        except Exception as exc:
            pass
        else:
            if rating:
                print(f'{k}: {rating}')

Sample run
Input your chess.com username? hikaru
username: hikaru
chess_daily: 2239
chess960_daily: 1231
chess_rapid: 2762
chess_bullet: 3257
chess_blitz: 3286

3. FIDE
"""Gets FIDE rating given FIDE Id.

Reference: https://github.com/cassiofb-dev/fide-api
"""

import urllib.request
import json

def get_fide_rating(fide_id):
    url = f"https://fide-api.vercel.app/player_info/?fide_id={fide_id}&history=true"
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
            if response.status == 200:
                data = json.loads(response.read().decode())
                name = data.get('name')
                title = data.get('fide_title')

                pinfo = data['history'][0]
                period = pinfo.get('period')
                classical_rating = pinfo.get('classical_rating')
                rapid_rating = pinfo.get('rapid_rating')
                blitz_rating = pinfo.get('blitz_rating')

                print(f'fide id: {fide_id}')
                print(f'name: {name}')
                print(f'title: {title}')
                print(f'period: {period}')
                print(f'classical rating: {classical_rating}')
                print(f'rapid rating: {rapid_rating}')
                print(f'blitz rating: {blitz_rating}')
            else:
                print(f"Failed to retrieve data for player ID {fide_id}. HTTP Status Code: {response.status}")
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        print(f"Error retrieving data: {e}")

fide_id = input('Input player FIDE ID? ')
get_fide_rating(fide_id)

Sample run
Input player FIDE ID? 46616543
fide id: 46616543
name: Gukesh D        
title: Grandmaster    
period: 2024-Jun      
classical rating: 2763
rapid rating: 2647    
blitz rating: 2627    


Yes you could do this, but it's also one line with curl and jq.
